# iOS - Choosing Model Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Can I use same model class for storing array data of multiple type array of dictionary with same keys?

Let's say for example I have a model class named **ProductDetail** used to store the product detail with key id, name and image and showing them in UITableViewController.

Now I have a different class named categories with same above mentioned keys.

Here is my model class:

```
class TrendingProductsData: NSObject {

    var id : Int! = 0
    var name : String! = ""
    var image : String! = ""

}
```

My question is can I use the **ProductDetail** model to store categories data as well?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a super model for common properties and extending the ones you have. Here is what I mean:

```
class BaseModel: NSObject {

    var id : Int = 0
    var name : String = ""
    var image : String = ""

    func setData(data: Any) {
        // Parse id, name and image from data
    }
}

class ProductDetail: BaseModel {
    // Add your other properties and/or functions
    var productProvider: String = "" // I added this to be an example

    override func setData(data: Any) {
        super.setData(data: data) // Since the key-value pairs are the same id, name and image will be parsed at BaseModel

        // Parse extra values such as  productProvider
    }
}

class Categories: BaseModel {
    // Add your other properties and/or functions
    var categorySubtitle: String = "" // I added this to be an example

    override func setData(data: Any) {
        super.setData(data: data) // Since the key-value pairs are the same id, name and image will be parsed at BaseModel

        // Parse extra values such as categorySubtitle
    }
}
```

This way you can create both `ProductDetail` and `Categories` models with common properties and if the need occurs you can add separate properties and functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to more complex structure like subCategory etc. it could be in a better way. But I think basically these classes are what you want.

Product can have detail only if isCategory is false.

```
class Product {

    var id : Int = 0
    var name : String = ""
    var image : String = ""
    var isCategory: Bool = false

    var productDetail: ProductDetail? = nil

}

class ProductDetail {
    var description : String = ""
    var price : Decimal?
}
```